# Searching the list in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one search box in one page i.e **header.html** file and the list on which i want to implement the search functionality is on another page i.e **content.html**. So how can i use angularjs search functionality in this case. Below is the html code.

**header.html**

```
<div class="input-group col-md-12 search-inner-page ">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
</div>
```

**content.html**

```
<div class="surveyList" ng-repeat="survey in allSurveys">
    <span class="checkbox" ></span>
    <div class="toogleSurvey row" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2  col-md-2">{{survey.Name}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-1 col-md-1">{{survey.Type}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-3 hidden-xs">{{survey.SurveyReference}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-3 hidden-xs">{{survey.CreatedDate}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2 hidden-xs SurveyLastChild">{{survey.Status}}</div>
        <div class="hidden-xs surveyListTool"  ng-show="hoverEdit">
        <a class="editSurvey" title="edit"></a>
        <a class="deleteSurvey" title="delete"></a>
        <a class="exportSurvey" title="export survey"></a>
        <a class="menuSurvey" title="menu"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**contentCtrl.js**

```
angular.module("adminsuite").controller("surveyController",['getAllSurveyService','AuthenticationService', '$scope','$rootScope', '$state', function(getAllSurveyService,AuthenticationService, $scope,$rootScope,$state){

getAllSurveyService.surveyList().then(
function( data ) {
    $scope.allSurveys = data;
    console.log($scope.allSurveys);
    if($scope.allSurveys.ErrorMessage){
      AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
      $state.go('login');
    }
}
 );

 }]);
```

**headerController.js**

```
angular.module("adminsuite").controller("headerController",['AuthenticationService','$rootScope','$cookieStore','$scope',function(AuthenticationService,$cookieStore,$scope,$rootScope){
   $scope.header = "Header";
  $scope.searchInSurvey = $scope.surveySearch;
     $scope.logout = function(){
                //$scope.dataLoading = true;
                AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
                console.log($cookieStore.get('globals'));
                //$state.go('login');
            };
  }]);
```

On typing something in the search box of **header.html** as mentioned above, it should search the content in **content.html** page.

Comment: do you have anything else in the header.html? Do use the input text element for anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You guys. I got the answer like this...

**header.html**

```
<div class="input-group col-md-12 search-inner-page">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q" ng-model="global.search">
                      <img src = "images/search.png" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail" >
                  </div>
```

**content.html**

```
<div class="surveyList" ng-repeat="survey in allSurveys | filter:global.search">
<span class="checkbox" ></span>
<div class="toogleSurvey row" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2  col-md-2">{{survey.Name}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-1 col-md-1">{{survey.Type}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-3 hidden-xs">{{survey.SurveyReference}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3  col-md-3 hidden-xs">{{survey.CreatedDate}}</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2 hidden-xs SurveyLastChild">{{survey.Status}}</div>
    <div class="hidden-xs surveyListTool"  ng-show="hoverEdit">
    <a class="editSurvey" title="edit"></a>
    <a class="deleteSurvey" title="delete"></a>
    <a class="exportSurvey" title="export survey"></a>
    <a class="menuSurvey" title="menu"></a>
</div>
```

**headerCtrl.js**

```
$rootScope.global = {
    search: ''
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use a `ng-change` on the input of header.html to update the `allSurveys` array.

Just add a `ng-change` and a `ng-model` to your input

```
<div class="input-group col-md-12 search-inner-page ">
  <input ng-model="yourCtrl.searchInput" ng-change="yourCtrl.searchInputChanged" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
</div>
```

In your controller you can add a function `searchInputChanged` that will filter the data based on searchInput using `.filter()`.

Comment: if am using two different controller for this two views then will it work inthat case ?

Comment: If you are using 2 controller you should create a service. You service could return the array "allSurveys" used in content.html and the controller userd in header.html can call the same service to set the filter.

Comment: can you tell me how can i use service in my example ? i have given the "surveyController" from where am getting all the surveys. How to create a filter for that

Comment: If you can setup a plunker or a JSFiddle with your example, I should be able to show you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your list of Surveys in a variable into a $rootScope, and get its value from another controller, like this:

```
//Controller that contains the list
$rootScope.surveysList = [s1,s2,s3,...,sn];
```

After that, you can get this variable and set into the controller scope where your input is.

```
$scope.allSurveys = $rootScope.surveysList;
```

Your input should be like this:

```
<input ng-model="surveySearch" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
```

And que query in your list template should be like this:

```
ng-repeat="survey in allSurveys | filter:surveySearch"
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: did you set the $rootScope as a dependency of both controllers?

Comment: I have added all the things that you have mentioned. Thing is that ng-model="surveySearch" its scope object variable for the particular controller associated to it. So if am trying to access this outside this html template how to access to do that ?

Comment: i have given the controllers also. If you check that and give me some codes how to do that, then it ll be great.